# Function continuity and invertibility for a separated function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $f:[0,1)\cup[2,3]\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by
>   $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
> x & x\in[0,1)\\
> x-1 & x\in[2,3]
> \end{cases}$$
>   Show that $f$ is continuous, one-to-one, and $f([0,1)\cup[2,3]) = [0,2]$. It then follows that $f$ is invertible (where defined). Show then that $f^{-1}:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ is not continuous.

### Conitnuity

Let $x_0\in [0,1)$, and suppose that $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta$.

Then if $\delta = \epsilon$, $0 < |f(x) - f(x_0)| = |x - x_0| < \delta = \epsilon$.

So $f$ is continuous on the interval $[0,1)$.

Let $x_0\in [2,3]$, and suppose that $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta$.

Then if $\delta = \epsilon$, $0 < |f(x) - f(x_0)| = |x - 1 - x_0 + 1| = |x - x_0| < \delta = \epsilon$.

So $f$ is continuous on the interval $[2,3]$.

The above also implies that the limit of $f$ at $x\to 1$ from the left is $1$, and the limit of $f$ as $x\to 2$ from the right is $1$.

Therefore $f$ is continuous.

> I feel like I'm messing something up with my claim about limits. It feels hand-wavy and I can't figure out why.

### One-to-one

Suppose that $f(a) = f(b)$, where $a,b\in [0,1).$

Then $f(a) = a = b = f(b)$. Therefore $a=b$.

Now suppose that $f(a) = f(b)$, where $a,b\in [2,3].$

Then $f(a) = a-1 = b-1 = f(b)$. Therefore $a=b$.

Because $f([0,1)) = [0,1)$, and $f([2,3]) = [1,2]$, no points in the first set are in the second set, therefore all points have been considered, and $f$ is one-to-one.

> I don't feel confident about this last step either

### $\pmb{f([0,1)\cup[2,3]) = [0,2]}$

As shown in the last part, since $f([0,1)) = [0,1)$ and $f([2,3]) = [1,2]$, $f([0,1)\cup[2,3]) = [0,2].$

> Is this legit?

### $\pmb{f^{-1}:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}}$ is not continuous

$$f^{-1}(x) = \begin{cases} x & x\in [0,1) \\ x+1 & x\in [1,2] \end{cases} $$
As shown in the first section, the limit of $f^{-1}(x)$ as $x\to 1$ from the left is $1$, and the limit of $f^{-1}(x)$ as $x \to 1$ from the right is $2$.

Therefore $f^{-1}(x)$ is not continuous.

> Not sure if I need to show what the inverse is

Comment: Is it stated in your excercise to show continuity of $f$ by the $\epsilon-\delta$ criteria? Otherwise just state that the identity function is continuous..

Comment: Your one-to-one argument is valid

Comment: The part about the image of $f$ is valid as well

Comment: I guess you should show that your stated inverse of $f$ is correct (even as it is obvious..)

Comment: @jack The exercise is just to show continuity, so I assumed I had to show it with $\epsilon-\delta$. Did I do that part right? It feels like my approach would also work for the inverse function, even though I showed that one was discontinuous.

Comment: Your continuity proof using the eps-delta criteria is not precise. 1) let x0 be given. 2) let eps be given. 3) find delta (specific to eps) jump in f is small enough. But as i said: it should be enough just to point out that the identity function is obviusly continuous.